# Django complex query from relational model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Using django-rest-framework, I have simple model

[image]

There is a Book which is getting translated, This book has chapters (each chapter has a name), each chapter has paragraphs. The Translation table contains foreign key to the Chapter(for chapter name) and paragraph range (from-to) because each translator can translate set of paragraphs in one translation, and the translation set can be out of order, but no overlap, for example a Translator1 can translate *Chapter 3 paragraph 4 to 10*, Translator2 can translate *Chapter3 paragraph 20 to 30* but Translator3 cannot translate *Chapter3 paragraph 9 to 20* because it leads to duplicate translation. for now this is done manually, I don't know how to set a constraint to prevent it.

```py
class Chapters(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name_fr = models.CharField(max_length=45, db_collation='utf8_unicode_ci')
    name_en = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_collation='utf8_unicode_ci', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_fr


class TheBook(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    chapterid = models.OneToOneField(Chapters,on_delete=models.PROTECT)  # Field name made lowercase.
    paragraphID = models.IntegerField()  # Field name made lowercase.
    paragraphText = models.TextField(db_collation='utf8_unicode_ci')  # Field name made lowercase.
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.paragraphText


class Translate(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    chapterid = models.ForeignKey(Chapters, to_field='id',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    parag_from = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    parag_to = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    translate = models.TextField(db_collation='utf8_unicode_ci', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return ("{}: {} - {}").format(self.chapter, self.parag_from ,self.parag_to)
```

Now my problem is selecting all the paragraphs that have translation, then the user clicks on the group of the translated paragraphs and reads the translation of that group

```py
class ParagraphList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, chapterName):

        # Get a list of paragraphs that has translation
        ParagraphList = Translate.objects.filter(
            chapter__name_en=chapterName
        ).values_list(
            'parag_from', 'parag_to', named=True
        ).order_by('parag_from')

        # variable to store the paragraph text
        ParagraphText = []

        # Loop through the List, and query the Book for the paragraphs in the 
        # range of parag_from to parag_to

        for i in range(len(ParagraphList)):
            ParagraphText.extend(list(
                Book.objects.filter(chapter__name_en=chapterName).filter(
                    paragraphID__range=list(ParagraphList[i]))
            ))

        serialized = BookParagSerializer(ParagraphText, many=True)
        return Response(serialized.data)
```

There is two problems with this code:

1. it's not efficient. I have to send multiple queries to the database to get the data
2. the returned data is like a list:

```js
[
 {
   "paragraphID": 1,
   "paragraphText":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur."
 },
 {
   "paragraphID": 2,
   "paragraphText":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur."
 },
 {
   "paragraphID": 3,
   "paragraphText":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur."
 },
....
]
```

I can't group them by translation. something like this:

```js
    [
    {
      "group":1,
      "parag_from":1,
      "parag_to":3,
      "translation_id":124,
      "context":[
                {
                  "paragraphID": 1,
                  "paragraphText":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur."
                },
                {
                  "paragraphID": 2,
                  "paragraphText":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur."
                },
                {
                  "paragraphID": 3,
                  "paragraphText":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur."
                },
      ]
    },
    {
      "group":2,
      "parag_from":9,
      "parag_to":11,
      "translation_id":321,
      "context":[
                {
                  "paragraphID": 9,
                  "paragraphText":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur."
                },
                {
                  "paragraphID": 10,
                  "paragraphText":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur."
                },
                {
                  "paragraphID": 11,
                  "paragraphText":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur."
                },
      ]
    },
    ...
]
```

In the serializer, I can't have multiple models, and this "group"ing I'm not sure how to do it.

I appreciate any suggestion.